# LESS: 2 mixins with same properties

Tags: less, mixins

In CSS if I want to have two classes with the same properties, I can write the following:

```
.class1,
.class2
{
  color:red;
}
```

I wish to obtain the same result for **LESS Mixins**, but the following code is not allowed:

```
.mixin1(),
.mixin2()
{
  color:red;
}
```

Is there a way to formally "**create a mixin duplicate**"?

Comment: Just invoke the base mixin from its alias `class2 {.class1();}`

Comment: INGENIOUS!!!! Thank you!!!! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following **seven-phases-max**'s suggestion, I can provide a more detailed answer:

**Simpler (original) solution**:

```
.class1
{
  color:red;
}

.class2 
{
  .class1;
}
```

that compiles into:

```
.class1 {
  color: red;
}
.class2 {
  color: red;
}
```

---

Alternatively is possible also to set an [hidden mixin](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature-not-outputting-the-mixin) thanks to `()` after its name, used as *transition* step:

```
.hidden-mixin()
{
  color:blue;
}

.class1,
.class2
{
  .hidden-mixin();
}
```

that compiles into:

```
.class1,
.class2 
{
  color: blue;
}
```